# How to avoid the page refresh at each server side event in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I've designed a web page in asp.net. And in that page i placed html control too like `<a>` & `<div>`. I have written one java script function which is hiding the `<div>` when i'm clicking on the `<a>` tag. Its working fine. But when i'm clicking on the asp.net button then page refresh occur again. And it is loading my previous design of the page. I set the `display:none` of the `<div>` at the design time. so it is hiding my `<div>` again when occuring any other server side event. And i don't want let it happen.

Javascript function-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       function toggle5(showHideDiv, switchTag) {
           try {
               '<%Session["temp"] = "'+more+'"; %>';
               var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
               var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchTag);
               if (ele.style.display == "block") {
                   ele.style.display = "none";
                   imageEle.innerHTML = 'More';
               }
               else {
                   ele.style.display = "block";
                   imageEle.innerHTML = 'Less';

               }
           }
           catch (err) {
               alert("Error");
           }
       }
</script>
```

html code is-

```
<div id="divSearch" style="float:left;height:100%;width:100%;">
<span style="float:right;height:27px;"><a id="displayText" href="#" onclick="javascript:toggle5('toggleText', 'displayText');">More</a></span>
</div>
<div id="toggleText" style="display:none;height:100%;width:100%;">
<div id="divCalls" style="width:24%;float:left;height:30%;">
<span style="float:left;width:100%;color:#3b5998;">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNoCall" runat="server" Text="No call made in " 
        AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="chkNoCall_CheckedChanged"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNoCall" runat="server" Width="12%" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox><span> days</span></span>
</div>
</div>
```

C#.net code of the Checkbox-

```
protected void chkNoCall_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkNoCall.Checked == true)
        {
            txtNoCall.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            txtNoCall.Enabled = false;
            txtNoCall.Text = "";
        }

    }
```

How to solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: Some JS and HTML would be helpful. I'm not sure what you're hiding and handling.

Comment: So basically you want to avoid having the asp.net button do a postback?

Comment: @AndersDaniel : It should only execute the button event. Because i want to handle other asp.net events too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this data inside the updatepanel like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <span style="float:left;width:100%;color:#3b5998;">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNoCall" runat="server" Text="No call made in " 
        AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="chkNoCall_CheckedChanged"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNoCall" runat="server" Width="12%" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox><span> days</span></span>

    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

hope this help

Comment: I placed my <div> whom i'm hiding in the update panel. But still it is working as earlier.

Comment: keep that div outside the panel as i have given in the code if you keep the div inside the panel it will refresh

Comment: yes it is working. But is there any other solution besides this? because i've many controls from the asp.net for which i'm using server side events.

Comment: there are several way to do partial postback,
1) You can do it by jquery Ajax method;
2) you can use IhttpHandler to post data to server;

Comment: in your scenario you should call your javascript function from server side code like following

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "script", "<script>toggle5(showHideDiv, switchTag)</script>", false);

Answer (score 3):

In your button click event, return false. this will prevent postback.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax to get the server side data instead of submitting the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

1. remove `runat=server` from the component (a component with `runat=Server` always submits a form.
2. use standard html controls
3. use javascript for html controls
4. it it's a component with `autopostback` feature; make `autopostback=false`

Comment: I know all this but i want to handle the server side event because i'm accessing database at the same page in another control.